# High UDP packages loss in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

I have the following method:

```
public void SendUDP(IEnumerable<byte[]> data)
{
  var udpClient = new UdpClient();   
  var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 55555);

  foreach (var message in data)
  {        
    udpClient.Send(message, message.Length, endPoint);
  }
}
```

Each element of `data` is about 1000 bytes length, `data.Count()` is about 100k. The problem is that almost 80% of all packages are lost, though the execution time is about 10 seconds. But when I add something like

```
foreach (var message in data)
  {        
    udpClient.Send(message, message.Length, endPoint);
    Console.WriteLine("Delay");
  }
```

there is no more package loss. Though, the execution time increases dramatically. Can anyone tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and share your research. This is caused by buffer space: once the send buffer is full, additional messages are silently dropped.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you for your reply! Maybe you could prompt the solution of my problem? Flush the buffer when it's full or something like that? I've searched all the related questions but found nothing that could help in my case...

Comment: Don't send data faster than it can be processed.